PHP MVC Routing Issue: Page does not update
I am creating a PHP application using an MVC architecture and I'm encountering an issue where the URL changes correctly, but the page content does not update accordingly. I have set up my application with a public directory containing my index.php file which handles all routing to controllers based on URLs. However, when I try to navigate to a new page via a link, the URL updates but the content remains the same. What am I doing wrong
.htaccess:
RewriteEngine On RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
index.php:
`    <?php

    ini_set('log_errors', 1);
    ini_set('display_errors', 1);
    error_reporting(E_ALL);


    // Load Composer's autoload to manage dependencies and class loading
    require_once __DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php';

    use App\Config\Database;

    // Define the base URL for easier reference throughout the application.
    define('BASE_URL', 'http://localhost/technique-db-mvc/public/');

    // Get the URL from the query string and sanitize it.
    $url = isset($_GET['url']) ? rtrim($_GET['url'], '/') : null;
    $url = filter_var($url, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL);
    $url = explode('/', $url);

    // Database connection setup for using Database class
    $db = Database::connect();

    $controller = (isset($url[0]) && $url[0] != '') ? 'App\\Controller\\' . ucfirst($url[0]) . 'Controller' : 'App\\Controller\\MainController';

    // Determine the method from the URL. Default to 'index' if no method is specified.
    $method = isset($url[1]) ? $url[1] : 'index';

    if ($url[0] === 'technique' && $url[1] === 'new') {
        $controller = 'App\\Controller\\MainController';
        $method = 'newTechnique';


    }
    // Extract any additional parameters from the URL to pass to the controller method.
    $params = array_slice($url, 2);

    echo "Controller: $controller<br>";
    echo "Method: $method<br>";
    print_r($params);

    // Check if the specified controller class exists.
    if (class_exists($controller)) {
        // Instantiate the controller if it exists.
        $controllerObject = new $controller($db);

        // Check if the controller has the method specified in the URL.
        if (method_exists($controllerObject, $method)) {
            // If the method exists, invoke it with the parameters.
            call_user_func_array([$controllerObject, $method], $params);
        } else {
            // Output an error message if the method does not exist.
            echo "Method does not exist.";
        }
    } else {
        // Output an error message if the controller class does not exist.
        echo "Controller does not exist.";
    }`

MainController.php:
`   
    /**
     * Controls the flow between the user interface and the model data processing,
     * coordinating responses based on user actions and input.
     */

    namespace App\Controller;

    use App\Model\CategoryModel;
    use App\Model\DifficultyModel;
    use App\Model\PositionModel;

    class MainController
    {
        private $_db;
        private $categoryModel;
        private $difficultyModel;
        private $positionModel;

        /**
         * Initializes the controller with model instances using a database connection.
         *
         * @param \PDO $db Database connection
         */
        public function __construct(\PDO $db)
        {
            $this->_db = $db;
            $this->categoryModel = new CategoryModel($this->_db);
            $this->difficultyModel = new DifficultyModel($this->_db);
            $this->positionModel = new PositionModel($this->_db);
        }

        /**
         * Gathers data from models and passes them to the view for rendering.
         * This is the main entry point for rendering the page requested by the user.
         */
        public function index()
        {
            include __DIR__ . "/../View/main_view.php";
        }

        public function newTechnique()
        {
            $categories = $this->categoryModel->readCategories();
            $difficulties = $this->difficultyModel->getAllDifficulties();
            $positions = $this->positionModel->getAllPositions();

            include __DIR__ . "/../View/add_new.php";
        }
    }`

